# Syntastic mode map per checker

Tags: vim, syntastic

Is there any way to separate the syntastic_mode (active vs. passive) depending on the checker? For example, I want it to be active for 'php' (syntax) errors but passive for 'phpcs','phpmd' (style) checkers. Joonty's phpqa plugin can do something like that, but I'd prefer to avoid overlapping plugins and I like syntastic. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Syntastic provides a map for that. The following makes syntastic passive for coffee script, but active for any other filetype.

```
let g:syntastic_mode_map = { 'mode': 'active',
            \ 'active_filetypes': [],
            \ 'passive_filetypes': ['coffee'] }
```

So the `mode` entry specifies the standard mode, while the other two entries specify the filetype specific behaviour.

Modify to your needs and put it in your .vimrc.

Answer (score 1):

Syntastic modes are per filetype, not per checker.  However, you can set `php` to active, set the list of `php` checkers to just `'php'`, and write a command to run `phpcs` and `phpmd` explicitly.  Perhaps like this:

```
let g:syntastic_mode_map = { 'mode': 'active' }
let g:syntastic_php_checkers = ['php']
cabbrev syc SyntasticCheck phpcs phpmd
```